# How should I handle windows/Linux paths in c#

Tags: c#, path

My intention is for my application to run on windows and linux.
The application will be making use of a certain directory structure e.g.

```
appdir/  
      /images
      /sounds
```

What would be a good way of handling the differences in file(path) naming differences between windows and linux? I don't want to code variables for each platform. e.g. pseudo code

```
if #Win32
  string pathVar = ':c\somepath\somefile.ext';
else 
  string pathVar = '/somepath/somefile.ext';
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` constant, which will be either `\` or `/`.

Alternatively, create paths using `Path.Combine`, which will automatically insert the correct separator.

Comment: Do you mean [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Would anyone mind commenting on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723456/windows-vs-unix-path-on-transfer-data-in-net as well? I've seem to have stumbled on a bit of a "loophole".

Comment: so all my path constants would look like:
`var tempPath = $"{Path.Directory.SeparatorChar}Appname{Path.Directory.SeparatorChar}Folder1{Path.Directory.SeparatorChar}temp1{Path.Directory.SeparatorChar}A";`

very nice and clear :)

Answer (score 7):

How about using [System.IO.Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to form your paths?

Windows example:

```
var root = @"C:\Users";
var folder = "myuser";
var file = "text.txt";
var fullFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, folder, file);

//Result: "C:\Users\myuser\text.txt"
```

Linux example:

```
var root = @"Home/Documents";
var folder = "myuser";
var file = "text.txt";
var fullFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, folder, file);

//Result: "Home/Documents/myuser/text.txt"
```

Comment: What if you need to work with linux paths while running the code on windows?

Comment: @YarekT Path.Combine is intended to be a cross platform path combiner.  I haven't tried it on Linux but it is supposed to work.

Comment: calling Path.Combine on windows creates windows paths. My project runs on and interacts with other linux machines, but some of our developers work on windows, so this creates inconsistencies.

Comment: The point is not hard code any platform dependent to the application... then how the two different hardcoded var root magic string helps? The app must run on both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mono. In the System.IO.Path class you will find:

```
Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar
Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
```

Hope this helps!